# How can I post a container in Storage api from loopback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopback

I already have declared my datasource ,my model and the connector between these.

**My model**

```
{
  "name": "container",
  "base": "Model",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Datasource**

```
"storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage"
  }
```

**My provider**

```
{
  "filesystem": {
    "root": "./server/storage"
  }
}
```

**And the Connector**

```
"container": {
    "dataSource": "storage",
    "public": true
  }
```

I try posting a object like {"Object":"container1"} into path "./server/storage" but I get the following error from callback.

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Path must be a string. Received undefined",
    "stack": "TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined.."
  }
}
```

Please who can help me to find my issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to post a container is, without using the loopback api. Create a folder that is gonna be the container into your provider path (being filesystem).
As simple as that!

Comment: sometimes the best solution is the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "name" instead of "Object" as key in your JSON object to create a new container/directory using the API.
`POST /api/containers {"name":"container1"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you need a programmatic way to add new containers, let's say for example you want to create a filesystem of sorts for new users. You can use the route below. "Container" is the name I called my Model, you can call yours whatever you'd like.

```
POST localhost:3000/api/container
```

Inside the body of the post request you have to have an attribute *name* and the value of the name can be the new container you're creating. The Strongloop/Loopback documentation, which can be found [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component-REST-API.html), is not accurate and neither is the error you get back when you try to post it with their directions.

```
"error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "TypeError",
    "message": "Path must be a string. Received undefined"
}
```

An excerpt of the code to send a post request to create a new container is also below.

```
var request = require("request");

var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/containers',
    body: { name: 'someNewContainer' },
    json: true
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```